# Create Wordpress Theme using Bedrock does not work

Tags: wordpress, xampp, themes, wordpress-bedrock

sorry if this is stupid question, but I am trying to setup Bedrock boilerplate for WordPress themes development. I have installed Bedrock successfully and I am also able to login to my dashboard. I have also setup connection to my database.

As long as I am aware, all new themes created should be served from /web/app/themes folder in the boilerplate.

However, if I create new folder with files for new theme (e.g. /web/app/themes/new_theme), this theme is not available from the Wordpress dashboard/appearance.

I am using XAMPP, phpMYADMIN as my local dev environment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to create a `style.css` file and add the theme header to it. Otherwise **WordPress** will not recognize it as a theme. So for a basic theme you must need to create a `style.css` file.

For further info please visit this below URL-

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked. I also had to add index.php. Silly me! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm Big fan of underscores.me , it will create WordPress structure boilerplate. Link( http://underscores.me/) so you should try this mate